# Adding "global" lister on entire JFrame to check fields changes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, listener

I've build an application that uses textfields, comboboxes, tables, etc. It also has a saving option that reads all fields and parses it in JSON and creates a text file. I added a JOptionPane that is displayed when the user tries to close it:
"Do you want to save before closing?
Yes | No |Cancel"

Is there any way that the application only displays this popup when there has been any change between the last time the user has modified any item?
I was thinking of adding a listener to every single UI stuff, but it seems quite a bad way to do it.

Is there a way to put a listener on a JFrame that checks if something in the UI has been changed?

The file saved is only modified when the user wants it, so I cannot use a WatchService on it...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to put a listener on a JFrame that checks if something in the UI has been changed?

Not that I know of.

However, maybe you can create your own custom class to handle this.

This class might give you some ideas:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class DataEntered implements DocumentListener
{
    private JButton button;
    private List<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

    public DataEntered(JButton button)
    {
        this.button = button;
    }

    public void addTextField(JTextField textField)
    {
        textFields.add( textField );
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener( this );
    }

    public boolean isDataEntered()
    {
        for (JTextField textField : textFields)
        {
            if (textField.getText().trim().length() == 0)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        checkData();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        checkData();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}

    private void checkData()
    {
        button.setEnabled( isDataEntered() );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JButton submit = new JButton( "Submit" );
        submit.setEnabled( false );

        JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(10);

        DataEntered de = new DataEntered( submit );
        de.addTextField( textField1 );
        de.addTextField( textField2 );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(textField1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(textField2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(submit, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The above code will enable a button when text is entered in all the text fields.

Obviously your logic would be different. You would just need to set an "updated flag" whenever text is entered into any text field.

Then your save logic would check the flag and reset it to false every time a save is done.

You would also, need to be able to  register different types of components with different types of listeners for each component that would indicate a change has been made. For example with a combo box you would use an ItemListener.

If you don't want to manually register components you could recursively find the components on each panel of the content pane and then write code to add the appropriate listener. To get the list of components you could use the [Swing Utils](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) class.

Comment: Looks like Swing Utils will do the job with a "general" listener you answered.
I also thought of reading the last saved file by the user and put it into a string and compare it by generating the json.

Thanks!